# why we need multi-column page layout? Why we do need sidebars?

Tags: interaction-design, layout, information-architecture

Some websites only have one column.

Some websites have multi-columns.

So why we need sidebar, or why we need multi-column page layout in web /print media ?

Is there any UX principles?

Comment: You need to be more specific, for a question like this it always depends on the situation you are in. There a principles around grid based design, chunking data, etc. But all these are really big topics. What are you working on now? Why did you ask this question? Answering this will help us.

Comment: in what situation, we use multi-column page layout, why? just give me some consideration

Comment: I feel it's to big of a question to answer here, maybe someone else smarter than me can give a good answer. Otherwise just Google 'Grid systems' for rationale to why we use columns.

Comment: It's information design. You read a novel, it's one column. You read the NY times, it's 10 columns (I think. Maybe it's 8 columns?).

Comment: grid is not equal to column.

Comment: grids are often used to form columns of information.

Comment: Often multi column layouts are used such that each column has a designated purpose.  The left side bar might be for navigation, and everything to the right is content, for example.

However there's a secondary reason to use multi-column layouts like this.  And that's the simple fact that people can have a hard time following lines of text when they span the entire width of the page.  They might accidentally skip a line as they're reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns often equate to the density or volume of information to be conveyed. News sites use three or more columns to present more content near the top of the screen. But many marketing or portfolio sites only need a single column to convey the few key points they need to get across.

There is no rule; let your content guide your layout.